# OOP PhP Problem of empty properties of a class while they are not empty when they are insert in databse. PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, oop, checkbox, null

Let me explain my problem.
I manage an app that allows to give roles to Users and give them access to different schemas, with a PostgreSQL database.

Each user is a "new User" object created by my User.class.php with those properties:

```php
class User{
    private $_idUser;
    private $_login;
    private $_password;
    private $_roles;
    private $_schemas;

    // Getter / Setter

    /**
     * Get the value of _roles
     */ 
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->_roles;
    }

     /**
     * Get the value of _schemas
     */ 
    public function getSchemas()
    {
        return $this->_schemas;
    }
}
```

Everything works, I can modify a User or create one, give him access to one or more schemas, assign him one or more roles.
Roles and Schemas can be selected in checkboxes.
As you can see :

For example, the checkbox of schemas :

```php
$schemas = SchemaManager::getList();
<div id="list-schemas">
    <?php
        foreach ($schemas as $elt) {
            echo '<input id="' . $elt->getSchema() . '" type="checkbox" name="schemas[]" value="' . $elt->getSchema() . '"/>' . $elt->getSchema() . '<br />';
        }
    ?>                          
</div>
```

Here is how to Update or Add a User in database by CREATING a new User:

```php
    case "addUsers":
        {
            $p = new User(["idUser" => $_POST["id"], "login" => $_POST["pseudo"], "password" => $_POST["password"], "roles" => isset($_POST["roles"]) ? $_POST["roles"] : null, "schemas" => isset($_POST["schemas"]) ? $_POST["schemas"] : null]);
            UserManager::add($p);
            break;
        }
    case "updUsers":
        {
            $p = new User(["idUser" => $_POST["id"], "login" => $_POST["pseudo"], "password" => $_POST["password"], "roles" => isset($_POST["roles"]) ? $_POST["roles"] : null, "schemas" => isset($_POST["schemas"]) ? $_POST["schemas"] : null]);
            UserManager::update($p);
            break;
        }
```

When I add a new User :

```php
object(User)[1]
  private '_idUser' => string '' (length=0)
  private '_login' => string 'azdazdzad' (length=9)
  private '_password' => string 'aadzAZAZD846@@' (length=14)
  private '_roles' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'role2' (length=5)
  private '_schemas' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'schematest2' (length=11)
```

It means that when add or update a User : roles and schemas are not empty, because the changes are done in database.
However, I would like to see the details of each Users, so I made that :

```php
$list = UserManager::getList();
var_dump($list);
foreach ($list as $elt) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><a href="#edit'.$elt->getIdUser().'">Details</a></td>';

    echo '<div class="lightbox" id="edit'.$elt->getIdUser().'">';
    echo '<figure>';
    echo '<a href="#" class="closemsg"></a>';
    echo '<figcaption><h4>'.$elt->getLogin().'</h4>';
    $roles=$elt->getRoles();
    var_dump($roles); // <-------------NULL
    if(isset($roles) && !empty($roles)){
        echo '<p>Membership of roles :</p>';
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            echo '<li>'.$role.'</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    $schemas=$elt->getSchemas();
    var_dump($schemas); // <-------------NULL
    if(isset($schemas) && !empty($schemas)){
        echo '<p>Grantee of schemas :</p>';
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($schemas as $schema) {
            echo '<li>'.$schema.'</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    echo '</figcaption>';
    echo '</figure>';
    echo '</div>';

    echo '</tr>';
}
```

& when I click on "Details" nothing appears for roles & schemas. WHY ???
Here is for example, a User when we do var_dump($list); :

```php
object(User)[10]
      private '_idUser' => string '24734' (length=5)
      private '_login' => string 'user10' (length=6)
      private '_password' => string '********' (length=8)
      private '_roles' => null
      private '_schemas' => null
```

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Can you also post your `getRoles()` method? Because the `User` class you posted does not have any methods in it.

Comment: I edit the post, I didn't paste all the Getters & Setters, only put Schemas & Roles.

Comment: Hmm, they are so simple that they shouldn't be the issue. If I was you I would dump the data during the whole process and carefully check if the null sneaks in somewhere. Also check if `$pers` actually has roles, and dump the `$p` variables after adding/updating users. And check what is written to your roles input to make sure it has the correct data to submit to your script.

Comment: I closely followed your instructions, then you can see in my Edit the var_dump on $p when I add or update a User.

Comment: Ok, so there is definitely an array with a role after creating the user, but after receiving the same user via `UserManager::getList();` it disappears - I would now take a closer look at the `UserManager::getList()` method, it seems like it changes the data.

Comment: In fact @Tox you are right. Let me show you with my new post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, thanks to @Tox, my problem was `UserManager::getList()`

Let me show you,

What I used to have :

```php
$q = pg_query("SELECT
    u.usesysid as idUtilisateur,
    u.usename as login,
    u.passwd as motDePasse,
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles r JOIN pg_catalog.pg_user u on(r.rolname=u.usename)
    WHERE usename !~ 'postgres' ORDER BY 1;");
```

What I have now :

```php
$q = pg_query("SELECT
    u.usesysid as idUtilisateur,
    u.usename as login,
    u.passwd as motDePasse,
    ARRAY(SELECT b.rolname FROM pg_catalog.pg_auth_members m JOIN pg_catalog.pg_roles b ON (m.roleid = b.oid) WHERE m.member = r.oid) as groupes,
    ARRAY(SELECT nspname FROM pg_namespace pn WHERE pg_catalog.has_schema_privilege(r.rolname, nspname, 'USAGE')= true AND nspname <> 'information_schema' AND nspname !~~ 'pg_%') as schemas
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles r JOIN pg_catalog.pg_user u on(r.rolname=u.usename)
    WHERE usename !~ 'postgres' ORDER BY 1;");
```

Comment: Hehe, actually getting the data from the DB does help indeed. :D

Comment: Yes, I was really tired :'( Thank you very much @Tox, you put me back on track !